# Automatic Connect to SMB server from 16.04 file manager

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, samba

Can the default file manager (Nautilus?) be configured to automatically connect to a SAMBA server located at \192.168.X.Y\Public?

Answer (score 1):

To automatically mount shares at boot do the following:

1. Edit the `/etc/samba/user` file using `gksu gedit /etc/samba/user` and add:

   ```
   username=samba_user
   password=samba_user_password
   ```

   - Note: KDE users must use kdesu rather than gksu and instead of Gedit they can use Kwrite as editor.
2. Change the permissions on the file for security:

   ```
   sudo chmod 0400 /etc/samba/user # permissions of 0400 = read only
   ```
3. Create a directory where you want to mount your share:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/samba_share
   ```
4. Using any editor, and add a line to `/etc/fstab` for your SMB share as follows:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
   gksu gedit /etc/fstab

   //myserver_ip_address/myshare  /media/samba_share  cifs  credentials=/etc/samba/user,noexec  0 0
   ```
5. To mount the share now, without rebooting:

   ```
   sudo mount /media/samba_share
   ```
6. To increase security at the expense of convenience, use this line in `/etc/fstab`:

   ```
   //myserver_ip_address/myshare  /media/samba_share  cifs  noauto,credentials=/etc/samba/user,noexec  0 0
   ```

   - This ensures a `password` is always asked before mount the shares folder

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

Comment: This is the model of how to post an answer:concise and easy to read & use.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1607090

A more elegant Nautilus only based solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.